# on body click I need to slide up which is slide down using button click(slideToggle)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am beginner for Jquery. I am using simple slide toggle on one button. Initially I am putting div in display none , when ever I am clicking on button I am using slide toggle function. It's working fine. But when I am clicking on body I need to slide Up(display:none) as well as on click of button also. I tried with $('body:not(element)') click function it's not working for me. Plz help me to resolve.

See this fiddle for normal slide functionality [**SlideToggle Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/qpmqsLan/)

This fiddle which I tried but not working [**Tried Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/qpmqsLan/1/)

```js
$("#legendButton").click(function(){
    $("#slidetooglelegends").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="LegendSlideSection">

 <div id="slidetooglelegends" style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid #a3a3a3;background:#fff;display:none;">
     hello slide
 </div>

 <button id="legendButton" class="btn btn-primary">Legend</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not too sure exactly what you want to happen.  The Fiddle shows the div sliding down on button click, then sliding back up on another button click.

Comment: @Dean.DePue: I want on click of body I need to hide the division

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you click on the slide button you are also technically clicking on the body, because they overlap each other. You should halt the event bubbling (if you will) so it only executes the first captured event and doesn't delegate to other event handlers.

This can be achieved with

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

See the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzcqvydu/1/)

```
$("#legendButton").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#slidetooglelegends").slideToggle("slow");
});

$("body:not(#legendButton)").click(function(){
    $("#slidetooglelegends").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to understand your question.

Still based on what i understood from your question, I have provided an answer here.

Hope this helps.

**HTML**

```
<div id="LegendSlideSection">

    <div id="slidetooglelegends" style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid #a3a3a3;background:#fff;display:none;">
           hello slide
    </div>

    <button id="legendButton" class="btn btn-primary">Legend</button>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#legendButton").click(function(){
    $("#slidetooglelegends").slideToggle("slow");
});
$("#legendButton").blur(function(){
    $("#slidetooglelegends").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/qpmqsLan/3/)